# What is Docker Config.Volumes?

Tags: docker

I am studying about docker volumes. I've tried using docker -v option to bind to a directory locally. After that, if i check with docker inspect, there is only information in Mount, but no information in Volumes.

```
~ $ docker inspect --format='{{json .Config.Volumes }}{{json .Mounts}}' 6171e4550c47 | jq
null
[
  {
    "Type": "bind",
    "Source": "/Users/kyounghwan.choi/test",
    "Destination": "/opt/dir",
    "Mode": "",
    "RW": true,
    "Propagation": "rprivate"
  }
]
```

When will the Volumes over there be filled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker supports two different persistence mechanisms.  You have created a [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) to cause a host directory to appear in the container, but you have not created a [(named) volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/).  That causes the `.Mounts` filed to show *something* has been mounted in the container, but there's not a volume *per se* that you've mounted.

That is: if you haven't mounted any named or anonymous volumes into the container, then `.Config.Volumes` will always be `null`, even if you have bind-mounted host directories.

Comment: After creating a volume with volume create and mounting it with the -v option, Volumes is null.